# Json with '@attr' in name to java POJO

Tags: java, json

I have the following json schema. The schema has a @ character in the schema. How does this translate to a java pojo?

Sample json

```
{
"@type":"employee",
"name":"John Doe"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Jackson Library and do something like:

```
public class Person {

    private final String type;

    private final String name;

    @JsonCreator
    public Person(@JsonProperty("@type") String type, @JsonProperty("name") String name) {
        this.type = type;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we have the annotations over the private variables rather than in the constructor?

Comment: No, as the JsonCreator over constructor with the JsonProperty over the fields is used when you are unmarshalling ( json to java pogo), usually if you have JsonProperty other the variables its for marshalling (java -> json), but its not required if the java field names are what you expect the json attributes to be.

Comment: It works. Thanks for the help. I have also found that JsonGetter and jsonsetter annotations work

Answer (score 0):

[Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) is another alternative:

```
public class Person{
  @SerializedName("@type")
  public String type;

  public String name;
}
```

then you can use it as :

```
Person person = new Gson().fromJson(YOURJSON,Person.class);
```